# Does not write text file from text input

Tags: java, jtextfield

I have written a code for "writing the content of textfield into a textfile". It has no error but it doesnt write anything in the text file ! Can anybody please help me and tell about my mistake ? or edit the code and put the whole code again.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e){
            handleActionPerformed(e);
        }
    });
}                                        

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

//do you really need to pass ActionEvent in this case?
protected void handleActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        String text = jTextField1.getText(); //get the text from the text field
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\Definition.txt"));
        writer.write(text); //write it in the file
        writer.flush(); //flush the write-buffer
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally { //always close the stream in finally block
        try {
            if(writer != null)
                writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException b) {
            b.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a debug statement in `handleActionPerformed` so you can tell if it is actually getting called.

Answer (score 3):

`handleActionPerformed(...)` does nothing. 
This should work I believe...

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
      handleActionPerformed(e);
  }                                     
}

//do you really need to pass ActionEvent in this case?
protected void handleActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
 BufferedWriter writer = null;
 try
 {
   String text = jTextField1.getText(); //get the text from the text field
   writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Definition.txt"));
   writer.write(text); //write it in the file
   writer.flush(); //flush the write-buffer
 }
 catch (IOException ioe)
 {
   ioe.printStackTrace();
 } 
 finally { //always close the stream in finally block
   try {
    if(writer != null) 
       writer.close();
   } catch(IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   } 
 }
}
```

Comment: hello. I used the editted code you wrote (right now I editted the topic with the new code and u can see this as latest version) but still nothing will appear of definition.txt ... can u take a look at my post above the page and see if sth is wrong again ? Thanks

Comment: @SunnY The `jbutton1.addActionListener...` code should be done when you create your GUI and set up all your other swing components. Not in its own method as you've done in the edited code in the question.